# The array from the JS file is not being sent to the symfony controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony5

There is a controller - MainController, it has a save Changes function, to which you need to pass an array from a Javascript file. Whatever I tried, everything does not fit, an empty request is output.

JS:

```
'use strict';

$(function () {

    $("#saveTableChange").click(function(e){
        var arrayMiss = [];
        $("#Table td").each(function(key){
            var arr= [];
            if($(this).attr('id').includes('TableName')===false) {
                if($(this).text()!==""){
                    arr.push($(this).attr('id'),$(this).text());
                    arrayMiss.push(arr);
                }
            }
        });


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            traditional: true,
            url: "../savechanges",
            data: JSON.stringify(arrayMiss),
        });
    });
} )(jQuery);
```

Controller:

```
  /**
     * @Route("/savechanges", name="save_changes")
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function saveChanges(Request $request)
    {

        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            dump($request->getContent());
        }
        echo json_encode($request);
        die();    

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(arrayMiss)` and in PHP do `var_dump($_POST, $_REQUEST, file_get_contents('php://input'))`

Comment: I also specify and all zeros are returned
`file_get_contents('php://input'))`
I don't understand what you need to enter here `php://input`

Comment: maybe I'm registering the url incorrectly? (registering manually)

Comment: There is different types of inputs in PHP. It depends on `Content-Type` header sent from FrontEnd. Try putting `dataType: 'JSON'` to your Ajax

Comment: Have you checked the actual request sent with your browser devtools?

Comment: No, but how is it done?

Comment: I think I'm referring to the url incorrectly. How is the path written in the url?
`dataType: 'JSON'` - Not help(

Comment: Usually it's right click > Inspect, then look for the Network pane. Reload the page and click `#saveTableChange`. You should see a bunch of request, select one and you should be able to see the data. How to open it could vary between browsers, do a google search if you cannot find it.

Comment: added a breakpoint after ajax execution and noticed that the array is in the local section, but this array is not in the global->jquery->contents section

Comment: By the way, when you click the button, `success: function` is called, not `error: function`

Comment: But did you check the request in the network pane and that the actual data being sent to the server is what's expected?

Comment: If I remove `<form>` from twig, the array is passed to `/savechange`, but then no forwarding occurs. I add redirection to js via `location.replace("journal.lock/save changes");` and the error `No route found for "GET /journal.loc/savechanges" (from "http://journal.loc/")`

Answer (score 0):

[Two files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k84Oq.png) are created with the same names, but with different types. [The first one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJL00.png) that is created from jquery has an array, but [the second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm53k.png) that is created from `<form action="{{ path('save_changes') }}" method="POST" id="formTableChange">` does not have this array. After redirection, the file with the array disappears, only [the one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPbVN.png) that was created by redirection remains

twig

`{% extends 'main/base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-center mt-5">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <h1 class="display-4 text-center">
                {{ thisUser_group }}
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-center mt-5">
            <div id="app">

            <form action="{{ path('save_changes') }}" method="POST" id="formTableChange">
            <table id="Table">
                 <th id="TableNAME" rowspan="2"> NAME</th>
                 <th id="TableMonth" colspan="{{ daysInMonth }}"><a href=""><</a>{{ monthList[monthNow-1] }}<a href="">></a>
                  <tr>

                 {% for i in range(1,daysInMonth) %}
                 <th>{{ i }}</th>
                 {% endfor %}
                                      </tr>
                                             </th>
                 {% for user_group in users_group %}

                   <tr>
                         <td id="TableName_{{ user_group.id }}">
                        {{ user_group.username }}
                        </td>
                         {% for i in range(1,daysInMonth) %}
                         <td contentEditable="true" id="{{ yearAndMonthNow }}-{{ i }}_{{ user_group.id }}"> </td>
                         {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </table>
                <button id="saveTableChange">Save</button>
            </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

{% endblock %}
{% block addjs %}
{% endblock %}`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know without seeing you html, but looks like your button in inside a `form`, and the click is submitting it, as that's the default behavior of buttons. To prevent it just disable the default functionality with [`.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

```
$("#saveTableChange").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var arrayMiss = [];
    // Rest of the code
});
```

Comment: In this case, the redirect does not occur and the selection via `if($(this).attr('id').includes('TableName')===false) {
                if($(this).text()!==""){
                    arr.push($(this).attr('id'),$(this).text());
                    arrayMiss.push(arr);
                }
            }` is not triggered

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов That's... quite strange. Are there any syntax errors in the browser's js console?

Comment: Only this warning `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "http://journal.loc/savechanges".`